# ¿Cómo se pide un valor de una variable en pl/pgSQL?

Tags: postgresql, plsql, plpgsql

quiero dejar la variable sin darle valor hasta que ejecute el cuadro anónimo. He probado diversas formas y todas me dan error. Sería el equivalente a &numero en pg/sql. ¿Cómo se haría sin necesidad de crear una función? Gracias por la ayuda!

```
do $$
declare
v_num numeric(8) := $1;
begin 
raise notice 'El número introducido es %', v_num;
end$$;
```

Answer (score 3):

Los objetivos de PL/pgSQL cuando se creo fueron:

- Poder ser usado para crear funciones y disparadores (triggers)
- Añadir estructuras de control al lenguaje SQL
- Poder realizar cálculos complejos
- Heredar todos los tipos, funciones y operadores definidos por el usuario
- Poder ser definido como un lenguaje "de confianza"
- Fácil de usar

PL/pgSQL es un lenguaje estructurado en bloques. Como mínimo tendremos un bloque principal en nuestro procedimiento almacenado y dentro de este podremos tener subbloques. Un bloque se define de la siguiente manera (Todo entre los corchetes [] es opcional):

```
[ << etiqueta >> ]
[ DECLARE
    declaraciones de variables ]
BEGIN
    codigo
END [ etiqueta ];
```

Estes es un ejemplo mucho más ilustrado
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para mayor información visitar la página: https://e-mc2.net/es/procedimientos-almacenados-y-plpgsql

Espero haya sido de ayuda!